# Duda sobre Clave Foranea

Tags: mysql, sql, modelorelacional

Estoy liado con una base de datos grande sin Integridad Referencial. Existe una tabla **usuarios** y muchas otras que almacenan distinta informacion sobre los mismos. Quiero aplicar dicha integridad a la BBDD agregando a todas las tablas necesarias una `FK` hacia la `PK` de la tabla users.

Las tablas disponen del campo necesario a convertir en FK pero este no esta referenciado, basicamente la relacion se realiza en la app a traves de Selects y Subselects a otras tablas y eliminar o hacer un update de una `PK` de la tabla users no tiene consecuencias en el resto de tablas.

Uno de los motivos es que deseo que cuando elimine un usuario de la tabla users... Todas las `FK's` (informacion de dicho usuario en otras tablas) desaparezca tambien.

Para ello estoy haciendo para cada tabla que alamacene informacion del usuario lo siguiente...

```
ALTER TABLE *name*
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_*name*_users FOREIGN KEY (FK_Column) REFERENCES users(PK_Column)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

La duda es que en la `BD` algunas de las columnas son `INDEX` y otras no...

- ¿Necesita una Clave foranea ser INDEX...? ¿Por que?
- ¿Que ocurre si establezco una relacion entre dos tablas PK y FK pero
  dicha FK no es un index de su tabla?
- ¿Por que debemos declarar una columna como INDEX cuando vamos a
  establecer una relacion PK / FK?

> La mayoria de los campos a convertir en FK tienen la llave que indica
>   que es un INDEX, pero hay algunos que no... ¿Debo convertirlos todos?
>   ¿Por que? ¿Que ocurre si no?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Necesita una Clave foranea ser INDEX...? ¿Por que?

No es obligatoria pero ayudará significativamente en la performance de las consultas que utilicen los join mediante PK / FK. En estos casos el motor de BBDD realizará los JOIN a través del indice para la tabla "hija".

> ¿Que ocurre si establezco una relacion entre dos tablas PK y FK pero
>   dicha FK no es un index de su tabla?

Al realizar las consultas join con PK / FK realizara busqueda lineal de los registros de la tabla "hija"

> ¿Por que debemos declarar una columna como INDEX cuando vamos a
>   establecer una relacion PK / FK?

Las primary Key siempre deben tener indice. pero no asi con FK, como se explica en las dos respuestas anteriores, es mejor generar un indice para la columna con el FK. Pero siempre se debe revisar el caso, recuerda que los índices también tienen un costo para ser mantenidas al cambiar la tabla, esto es, que debes tener cuidado si la tabla con indice recibe muchos updates/inserts.

[Aqui hay una explicación más ilustrada y con datos](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3207/make-sure-all-join-columns-are-indexed/)

Answer (score 1):

Las claves foráneas tienen como *función principal* llevar la base datos a la tercera forma normal, evitando así la redundancia de datos.

Ahora, las claves foráneas **NO** deben ser obligatoriamente indices, ya que tranquilamente puedes crear una FK sin indice y el motor de BD te lo permite.

Por otro lado las claves foráneas se les asigna `indices` para **mejorar el rendimiento** de la base de datos, por ejemplo:

> al eliminar una PK con un borrado en cascada y no disponer de una
>   forma óptima para buscar en la tabla aquella clave a
>   borrar (FK), a pesar de tratarse de una única fila, debemos acabar
>   recorriendo toda la tabla...

Por el contrario cuando se cuenta con un indice en la FK el rendimiento es mucho mejor al ejecutar ciertas tareas como por ejemplo el borrado en cascada.